# Java Spring JDBC. PSQLException: Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a new user and receive the following error:

```
ERROR 16444 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO users (name, surname, year_of_birth, email, password, position_id) VALUES (:name, :surname, :year_of_birth, :email, :password, (SELECT id FROM positions WHERE name = :position))]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

Here is my Controller:

```
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String create(Model model, @RequestParam Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        setParametersForUser(userDto, parameters);
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.createUser(userDto));
        return "user";
    }

    private void setParametersForUser(UserDto userDto, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        userDto.setName(parameters.get("name").toString());
        userDto.setSurname(parameters.get("surname").toString());
        userDto.setYearOfBirth(Integer.valueOf(parameters.get("year_of_birth").toString()));
        userDto.setEmail(parameters.get("email").toString());
        userDto.setPassword(parameters.get("password").toString());
  userDto.setPositionDto(UserDto.PositionDto.valueOf(parameters.get("position").toString()));
    }
```

Here is my Service:

```
@Override
public UserDto createUser(UserDto userDto) {
    User newUser = userDao.createUser(toUser(userDto));
    return toDto(newUser);
}

private User toUser(UserDto userDto) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(userDto.getId());
    user.setName(userDto.getName());
    user.setSurname(userDto.getSurname());
    user.setYearOfBirth(userDto.getYearOfBirth());
    user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    user.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());
    user.setPosition(User.Position.valueOf(userDto.getPositionDto().toString()));
    return user;
}
private UserDto toDto(User entity) {
    UserDto dto = new UserDto();
    dto.setId(entity.getId());
    dto.setName(entity.getName());
    dto.setSurname(entity.getSurname());
    dto.setYearOfBirth(entity.getYearOfBirth());
    dto.setEmail(entity.getEmail());
    dto.setPassword(entity.getPassword());
    dto.setPositionDto(UserDto.PositionDto.valueOf(entity.getPosition().toString()));
    return dto;
}
```

Here is Dao:

```
private static final String INSERT = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, year_of_birth, email, password, position_id) VALUES (:name, :surname, :year_of_birth, :email, :password, (SELECT id FROM positions WHERE name = : position))";

@Override
public User createUser(User user) {
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    Map<String, Object> parameters = getParameters(user);
    SqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource(parameters);
    int rowsUpdated = template.update(INSERT, source, keyHolder, new String[]{"id"}); //mistake is here 
    if (rowsUpdated != 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't create user");
    }
    Long id = Optional.ofNullable(keyHolder.getKey()).map(Number::longValue).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Can't create user"));
    return getUserById(id);
}

private Map<String, Object> getParameters(User user) {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("name", user.getName());
    parameters.put("surname", user.getSurname());
    parameters.put("year_of_birth", user.getYearOfBirth().toString());
    parameters.put("email", user.getEmail());
    parameters.put("password", user.getPassword());
    parameters.put("position", user.getPosition().toString());
    return parameters;
}
```

User must be as follows:

```
public class User
private Long id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private Integer yearOfBirth;
private String email;
private String password;
private Position position;

public enum Position {
    CEO,
    MANAGER,
    WORKER
}
```

And tables in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE positions (
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE users (
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   surname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   year_of_birth INTEGER,
   email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   position_id BIGINT REFERENCES positions,
   deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT false NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO positions (name)
VALUES ('CEO'),
     ('MANAGER'),
     ('WORKER');

INSERT INTO users (name, surname, year_of_birth, email, password, position_id)
VALUES ('Tom','Ands',1999,'Tom@ggg.com','R887h24hs',(SELECT id FROM positions WHERE name = 'WORKER'));
```

Where can be the problem? Pls help

Comment: Hi &welcome! The error message complains about "update" statement, you show only code relevant to "insert" so far..?

Comment: Sorry! I mixed up. The error for "create" and "update" is the same. 
bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO users (name, surname, year_of_birth, email, password, position_id) VALUES (:name, :surname, :year_of_birth, :email, :password, (SELECT id FROM positions WHERE name = :position))]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.] with root cause

Comment: Ok, np, thank you! (You can [edit] post;)

Comment: To the problem: [JdbcTemplate#update](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) has (currently) 7 (6+1) overloads! ..please precise, which you want to use/is suited to your scenario...then use it accordingly!